# How do I remove a tachometer cable from a motorcycle engine?

Tags: motorcycle, tachometer

I am trying to remove the engine from a 1978 Yamaha XS400. The tachometer cable goes directly into the top of the engine - I'm guessing it runs off a worm gear on camshaft. There is a screw at a 90 degrees to where the cable joins the top of the engine, almost seems like it's meant to clamp it in place.

The workshop manual simply says loosen the screw and pull out the cable. But the cable wont budge.

Would anyone know how to remove this?

Comment: Did you remove the screw? Is the cable housing corroded into place?

Comment: I assume "wiggle it furiously" and "pull it like you've trying to pull a tree out by the roots" aren't the answers you're looking for?

Comment: @CharlieRB yes I removed the screw completely. The cable housing and engine are in very good condition for there age - not rust or corrosion at all.

Comment: That's good to know. You might try a little penetrating oil. There may be a small amount of corrosion between the cable housing and the engine that you can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a parts diagram, it appears that the screw is simply there to extend into a channel at the end of the cable sleeve, and lock the sleeve from moving out of the engine. If you can fully remove the screw to ensure it's not longer interfacing with the cable sleeve, there shouldn't be anything else holding it in. If it's stuck, it could be a matter of crud built up somewhere that's preventing the sleeve from sliding out of the engine.

It may help to wiggle and spin the sleeve to break it free as you try pulling it out. You can also try to remove the inner cable from the sleeve by sliding it out the other end. I wouldn't expect them to be held together in any way, and that will give you an idea if it's the cable inner or the sleeve that's binding.

[1978 XS400 Tachometer, Speedometer](http://www.partzilla.com/parts/search/Yamaha/Motorcycle/1978/XS400-2E/SPEEDOMETER+-+TACHOMETER/parts.html)

Part number is: 1L9-83560-01-00

[image]